# data.json is not a function reactjs using Fetch API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I have delete function using fetch api but while deleting, I'm getting this error, `data.json is not a function`

This is my code

```
export const deleteLeaveType = async id => {
  const response = await fetch(
   `${API_LINK}/route/route/route/${id}`, {
    method: 'delete',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${Auth.getToken()}`,
     },
   }
  );
  return getData(response);
};
```

I'm calling it in another file

```
const deleteLeaveType = async id => {
  let deleteLeaveType = isLeaveType.filter(
    item => item.id !== id
  );

  await CalendarManagementAPI.deleteLeaveType(id)
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data.json());
      setLeaveType(deleteLeaveType);
    });
    setLoadingLeaveTypes(false);
    fetchLeaveTypes();
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
};
```

Comment: What is `getData`? Also, you don't need to use `.then` if you're using `await`; just do `const data = await CalendarManagementAPI.deleteLeaveType(id)`.

Comment: That's the promise response.

Comment: @AlyssaReyes did you check out the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

#### Main issue:

The main issue you're running into is that in your top `deleteLeaveType` function, you're ending with `return getData(response)`, instead of just returning whatever you received from your `fetch` request.

As you can see from [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), the normal way to use `fetch` is to just do `const response = await fetch(...)` (as you've already done), then immediately after call `data.json()` (which is another async function, by the way). However, your `getData(response)` function is probably not returning exactly what you expect.

#### Other comments:

As mentioned in the comments, you probably shouldn't be using `async` / `await` at the same time as `.then()`. These are two different ways of handling async functions, so only one should be used at a time.

In your `deleteLeaveType` function, if you prefer using `.then` to handle async functions you can get rid or `async` and `await` like this:

```
// remove 'async' from function declaration
const deleteLeaveType = id => {
  // keep original code      

  // remove 'await'
  CalendarManagementAPI.deleteLeaveType(id)
    .then(data => {
      // ... everything else the same
};
```

**OR** to use `async` / `await` the right way, like you used in the first `deleteLeaveType` in your question, do this:

```
const deleteLeaveType = async id => {
  let deleteLeaveType = isLeaveType.filter(
    item => item.id !== id
  );

  let data = await CalendarManagementAPI.deleteLeaveType(id);

  // ... the rest of your code
};
```

Here's an interesting article explaining some ideas for error handling with `async` / `await`, if you're interested: [Better error handling with async / await](https://dev.to/sobiodarlington/better-error-handling-with-async-await-2e5m)

I would also recommend not using the same variable name `deleteLeaveType` for two functions *and* an array. This can get a bit confusing as to what you're referencing at any given moment in time.